# Object exists but still getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have made a functionality in my website that is that we can add comments to a post and the user who has posted that can edit the comment he posted. But unfortunately that's not working. 
Here is my code that is printing those comments out:

```
var offers = <? php echo $offers = PostOffer::GetOffers($_GET["id"]); ?> ; <? php $decodedOffers = json_decode($offers); ?> <? php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($decodedOffers); $i++) { ?>
    var date = offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Date.split(" ");
    document.write('<div class="row-fluid offer">' +
        '<div class="span2">' +
        '<img class="profile_picture" src="' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Picture_Path + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="span10">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="username">' +
        '<p style="font-weight: bold;">' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Name + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '<p class="content">' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Text + '</p>' +
        '<div class="btn-group pull-right">');
    if (posted_by == <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]); ?> && offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].User_ID != <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]); ?> ) {
        if (offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Accepted == 0) {
            document.write('<button class="accept_offer btn btn-inverse hide" data-offer-id="' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Offer_ID + '"><i class="icon-white icon-check"></i> Accept Offer</button>');
        } else {

            document.write('<button class="accept_offer btn btn-inverse" data-offer-id="' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Offer_ID + '"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Unaccept Offer</button>');
        }
    }
    if (posted_by == <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]); ?> && offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].User_ID != <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]); ?> ) { <? php
        $userId = $decodedOffers[$i] - > {
            "User_ID"
        };
        $withUserId = User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]);
        $conversationId = Conversation::CheckIfConversationExists($userId, $withUserId);
        if ($conversationId != null) { ?>
                document.write('<button class="btn btn-inverse" onclick="window.location.href=\'conversation.php?id=<?php echo $conversationId; ?>\'"><i class="icon-white icon-envelope"></i> Contact Person</button>&nbsp;'); <? php
        }
        elseif($conversationId == null) { ?>
                document.write('<button class="btn btn-inverse" href="" class="no_link" onclick="showContactPersonModal(' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].User_ID + ')">Contact this person</a>&nbsp;'); <? php
        } ?>
    }
    document.write('</div>');
    document.write('<textarea class="hide span12 edited_content">' + offers[ <? php echo $i; ?> ].Text + '</textarea>'); < /script>
                                        <script>
                                        document.write('<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer(<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>,' + offers[<?php echo $i; ?>].Offer_ID + ',' + document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[<?php echo $i; ?>] + ');\'>Save Edits</button > & nbsp;
    '+
                                        ' < button type = "button"
    class = "hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits" > Cancel Edits < /button>' +
                                        '</div > ' +
                                        ' < /div>' +
                                        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                                        '<div class="date">' +
                                        '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span > < /strong>' + date[0] + '</p > ' +
                                        ' < /div>');
                                if(offers[<?php echo $i; ?>].Username == "<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>") {
                                    document.write('<div class="controls pull-right">' +
                                                    '<a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a > & nbsp;
    ' +
                                                    ' < a href = ""
    class = "no_link"
    onclick = "showDeleteOfferModal(' + offers[<?php echo $i; ?>].Offer_ID + ');" > Delete < /a> |&nbsp;' +
                                                    '</div > ');
                                }
                                document.write(' < /div>' +
                                            '</div > ' +
                                        ' < /div>' +
                                    '<hr / > ');
                            <?php } ?>
```

And this is the code which is rendered(I've tried to keep it simple as possible):

```
<div class="row-fluid offer">
    <div class="span2"><img class="profile_picture" src="admin/profile_pictures/mas.png"></div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="username">
                <p style="font-weight: bold;">Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                <p class="content" style="display: block;">rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo </p>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
                <textarea class="hide span12 edited_content" style="display: none;">rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo  rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo rajjo </textarea>
                <script>
                    document.write('<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer(20,' + offers[0].Offer_ID + ',' + document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[0] + ');\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;'+
                    '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                          '<div class="date">' +
                          '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>' + date[0] + '</p>' +
                          '</div>');
                    if(offers[0].Username == "mas") {
                    document.write('<div class="controls pull-right">' +
                                '<a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a>&nbsp;' +
                                '<a href="" class="no_link" onclick="showDeleteOfferModal(' + offers[0].Offer_ID + ');">Delete</a> |&nbsp;' +
                                '</div>');
                    }
                    document.write('</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<hr />');

                </script><button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick="editPostOffer(20,45,[object HTMLTextAreaElement]);" style="display: none;">Save Edits</button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits" style="display: none;">Cancel Edits</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="date">
                <p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>2014-01-03</p>
            </div>
            <div class="controls pull-right"><a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="" class="no_link" onclick="showDeleteOfferModal(45);">Delete</a> |&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS which is the main thing:

```
function editPostOffer(postId, offer_id, edited_content) {
    $.post("admin/post_offer/edit_post_offer.php", {id: offer_id, text: edited_content.value}, function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            window.location.href = "post.php?id="+postId;
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Now what that code does is that it shows us a paragraph with the comment's text. Then there is a edit link at the bottom. When we click the link the paragraph is hidden and a textarea is shown with the comment's text already in it. Then there are two buttons also shown at the same time when the textarea is shown. Those are the save edit and cancel edit. When we click the save edit button it calls a function named `editPostOffer` this function takes in two parameters, the id of the comment and the edited_content.

Now the problem is that as you can see on the onclick of the save edit I have done this:

```
onclick=\'editPostOffer(<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>,' + offers[<?php echo $i; ?>].Offer_ID + ',' + document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[<?php echo $i; ?>] + ');\'
```

Which is rendered as:

```
onclick=\'editPostOffer("20","' + offers[0].Offer_ID + '",' + document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[0] + ');\'
```

And when the function `editPostOffer` gets called it should get it's values like this:

```
editPostOffer("20", document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[0]);
```

But it's getting it like this:

```
editPostOffer("20", undefined);
```

And so that's why the console is showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

And when I manually type this in the console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[0]
```

I get the textarea with the value of the comment.

Can anyone please tell me why is the console showing the error "undefined" even when there is an object existing with the same value?

Comment: And you are sure `$_GET['id']` is set?

Comment: Yes it is! I am 100000% sure. I can see it in the URL :P

Comment: Well, it outputs as `&quot;20&quot;,&quot;46&quot;`, so there is something going wrong.

Comment: @putvande where'd you see that?

Comment: After your line _And this is the code which is rendered(I've tried to keep it simple as possible):_ search for `editPostOffer`.

Comment: @putvande I can't see it

Comment: @putvande so what should I do now? :/ I saw it. :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44442/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-putvande)

Answer (score 0):

quotation marks are wrong.

Remove the escape on the first and last one. Also there is a missing quotation mark after ("edited_content")[0].

Rendered text should be:
onclick='editPostOffer("20","' + offers[0].Offer_ID + '",' 
+ document.getElementsByClassName("edited_content")[0]' + ');\'

Comment: No, it's not the problem